# Rails - Faker gem inside controller to generate fake names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to add something like below to my ConversationsController. Is this possible?

```
Conversation.create(author_id: current_user.id,receiver_id: @receiver.id, name:Faker::Name.name)
```

But i'm getting an

> uninitialized constant PersonalMessagesController::Faker error

Comment: Can you give a space between `name` and `Faker::Name`. It should be `name: Faker::Name.name`

Comment: I don't think spacing matters, but I tried it with the space and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed faker gem outside test group in gem file.

Then generate name with

```
Faker::Name.name
```